# How to pass custom values to identityserver4 with oauth?

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

Our application is tenant based and we want to pass an id to the ProfileService of IdentityServer4. How is it possible to pass a custom value to profileservice coming from the first request?

https://localhost:44390/connect/authorize?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8100/auth/callback&client_id=client.id&response_type=code&state=Ou3ZXnwaKM&scope=openid email offline_access&**userId=08d9e62e-c6ab-4555-8820-3ba9b3e80752**&code_challenge=rF2DzrNUpzAdVi-XQV1DIq84mTaAnjZLpaWwcULt8zk&code_challenge_method=S256

The userId is not accessible in the profileservice.

Comment: Why do you think this is an Oauth issue?  Parameters like ID are sent from client to server in on e of two ways 1) The parameters are after the question mark in the URL like code posted 2) Parameters are sent in HTTP Headers.  Oauth is credentials that are used for the connection.  You would get a different error message of the credentials were wrong.

Comment: @jdweng the question is valid itself, it is oidc-specific, the problem is that oidc protocol defines a very few acceptable parameters. please see my answer for the reference. wish you removed you cloce/down votes.

Comment: @d_f : Agree.  In this case the parameters are part of the URL after the question mark and are required.  Example looks like following : Location: https://server.example.com/authorize?
    response_type=code
    &scope=openid%20profile%20email
    &client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
    &state=af0ifjsldkj
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb

Answer (score 1):

Authorization request [has predefined structure](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest). IdentityServer is a certified OpenId Connect protocol implementation, so you can't introduce *any* custom parameter you want.

According to the spec the only two "free" parameters are the `state` which is used by clients and should be sent back with response as it is, and `acr_values` which is specially aimed for sending additional parameters to the server.

So you just add `&acr_values=userId:08d9e62e-c6ab-4555-8820-3ba9b3e80752` to your authorization request and the value is accessible at IdentityServer. Moreover you mentioned tenant and IdentityServer has advanced support for the `tenant` acr_value. Just provide `&acr_values=tenant:DevPlayground` and the value will be accessible as

```cs
IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl).Tenant;
```

In general you can pass as many `acr_values` as you want separating them with spaces: `&acr_values=userId:08d9e62e-c6ab-4555-8820-3ba9b3e80752 tenant:DevPlayground`