# Redirect to a website using basic authentication ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to redirect to a page that uses basic authentication. The only way I have got it to work so far is by adding `username:password@url` to the url of the page I'm trying to redirect to, which does not work if the web app is used in an Iframe.

The second method I have tried is the code shown here. In the response I get a status Ok but when trying to redirect to the url return in the response, the page will prompt a basic authentication pop up.

```
var username = "username";
var password = "password";

var client = new RestClient(url);

client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username,password);
client.PreAuthenticate = true;

// Have also used the line above instead, they both return status OK
// request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials)

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

return Redirect(response.ResponseUri.ToString());
```

Comment: Do you mean OAUTH authentication?  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019813/how-to-pass-custom-values-to-identityserver4-with-oauth?force_isolation=true#comment125597704_71019813

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retaining authorization header in RestSharp during redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374247/retaining-authorization-header-in-restsharp-during-redirects)

Comment: Thank you for your replies, that does not help because there is a request being made to an API, hence a response will be returned, on my situation Im trying to redirect to a completely different page, that will ask for basic authentication, 1 username and password for everyone (I know there is no security on doing this, but it is not up to me to decide)

Comment: Most browsers don't allow you to include credentials in the URL for security reasons. For example, `https://www.google.com/somelongstring@pass:evilbadguys.com/phishing` looks like a valid Google URL to most users.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you'd think that making a request **on the server** with BASIC authentication credentials would have any effect on the request made **on the client**.

Comment: @RichardDeeming this is part of a simple web app that will pick some parameters and generate a URL from a SQL Server Report Services server and display a report, and there is no way of removing authentication to access the reports.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this?  I'm running into the exact same situation.